# How to get weights for the embedding layer after training using Pytorch's nn.Transformer?

Tags: python, pytorch, embedding, transformer-model

I'm a biginner of NLP. Also, I am not an English speaker, so I apologize for my poor English.

I recently try to train a model using Pytorch's nn.Transformer module to get weights for the embedding layer after training.
I'm training on my own data from the Transformer tutorial on Pytorch. (https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transformer_tutorial.html)

Currently, I use this code to get weights for the embedding layer after training.
Will this get accurate weights after training?

```
import time

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
lr = 5.0  # learning rate
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, 1.0, gamma=0.95)

def train(model: nn.Module) -> None:
    model.train()  # turn on train mode
    total_loss = 0.
    log_interval = 200
    start_time = time.time()

    num_batches = len(train_data) // bptt
    for batch, i in enumerate(range(0, train_data.size(0) - 1, bptt)):
        data, targets = get_batch(train_data, i)
        output = model(data)
        output_flat = output.view(-1, ntokens)
        loss = criterion(output_flat, targets)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 0.5)
        optimizer.step()

        total_loss += loss.item()
        if batch % log_interval == 0 and batch > 0:
            lr = scheduler.get_last_lr()[0]
            ms_per_batch = (time.time() - start_time) * 1000 / log_interval
            cur_loss = total_loss / log_interval
            print(f'| epoch {epoch:3d} | {batch:5d}/{num_batches:5d} batches | '
                  f'lr {lr:02.2f} | ms/batch {ms_per_batch:5.2f} | '
                  f'loss {cur_loss:5.7f}')
            total_loss = 0
            start_time = time.time()

def evaluate(model: nn.Module, eval_data: Tensor) -> float:
    model.eval()  # turn on evaluation mode
    total_loss = 0.
    with torch.no_grad():
        for i in range(0, eval_data.size(0) - 1, bptt):
            data, targets = get_batch(eval_data, i)
            seq_len = data.size(0)
            output = model(data)
            output_flat = output.view(-1, ntokens)
            total_loss += seq_len * criterion(output_flat, targets).item()
    return total_loss / (len(eval_data) - 1)

best_val_loss = float('inf')
epochs = 20

with TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:
    best_model_params_path = os.path.join(tempdir, "best_model_params.pt")

    for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
        epoch_start_time = time.time()
        train(model)
        val_loss = evaluate(model, val_data)
        elapsed = time.time() - epoch_start_time
        print('-' * 89)
        print(f'| end of epoch {epoch:3d} | time: {elapsed:5.2f}s | '
            f'valid loss {val_loss:5.7f}')
        print('-' * 89)

        if val_loss < best_val_loss:
            best_val_loss = val_loss
            torch.save(model.state_dict(), best_model_params_path)

        scheduler.step()
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(best_model_params_path)) # load best model states

emb=model.embedding.weight
embedding_weight=emb.detach().numpy().copy()
```

Comment: This code is fundamentally sound in training and evaluation of Transformers network. You're extracting the weights from the embedding layer with `model.embedding.weight`. This is a correct method to access the weights. The `detach().numpy().copy()` portion ensures that you're getting a numpy array copy of the weights, disconnected from the gradient graph.